# Missing local repository

Tags: git

I was trying to push to a local repository in an internal network, but even if the origin was added successfully I could not push a commit.

Yet I added an origin, added files and make a commit.

```sh
mfijak@beslap162 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/WebPluginPresenter (dev)
$ git remote -v
origin  file:////...//source//ManagementDashboard.git (fetch)
origin  file:////...//source//ManagementDashboard.git (push)

mfijak@beslap162 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/WebPluginPresenter (dev)
$ git status
On branch dev
nothing to commit, working tree clean

mfijak@beslap162 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/WebPluginPresenter (dev)
$ git push origin master
fatal: '//...//source//ManagementDashboard.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Suppose the path of the local repository is `/path/to/foo.git`. You can use either `git remote add origin /path/to/foo.git` or `git remote add origin file:///path/to/foo.git`.

Comment: git remote -v shows that origin is added properly

Comment: It seems the path has redundant `/`.

Comment: ok, it worked, now im having error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'file:///besfs01//source//ManagementDashboard.git'

Comment: `file:///besfs01/source/ManagementDashboard.git` would be okay. The first 2 `/` are part of `file://`, which indicates the file protocol, similar to `http://` and `https://`. The rest `/` are separators in the path. For the push failure, try `git push origin -u master` or `git push origin -u master:master`.

Comment: thanks for help, it turned out that the repository was not initialized inside file:///besfs01/source/ManagementDashboard.git